# bootstrap navbar is breaking when screen is resized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap navbar looks good on full laptop screen, on resizing it to smaller width it breaks.

This is my html part.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav head-nav">
            <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">our plan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">visit blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Following is my css section :

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.head-nav {
 margin-left: 36%;
}
.head-nav li{
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 26px;
}

nav.head-nav:last-child {
    margin-right: 0% ;
}
```

This is what it looks in full width: 
[image]
This is how it breaks on resize :
[image]
I am not great fan of using pixels, want to achieve this with % only ! 
any bootstrap classes can help me here ? I want navbar to be responsive on smaller width.

Comment: You'd either want to use bootstrap's classes that obey the responsive breakpoints, or just write your own CSS to change the menu to your liking at each breakpoint.

Comment: I am fine with either way. but preferably I would like to go with bootstrap classes. If that's not affordable then will go with Custom CSS !

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.js? Your nav isn't collapsing

Comment: I have included and it collapses but after compressing it below 768px.. but after in 770-850px, it breaks into multiple rows as I have posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same problem on my website quite recently. I am not aware of any solution that doesn't use pixel screen sizes and I think there is no point in using % instead of px. See below why.

The problem is with the point at which the `navbar` collapses. By default, Bootstrap collapses at `768px`. If you increase this, your navbar will collapse sooner and your problem will disappear.

The best way to do this is to customize your bootstrap file and change the `@grid-float-breakpoint` to `850px` (or whatever size you need, in case this is not the point at which you want to collapse). You can easily customize bootstrap 3 from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=9720390

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. else the point(pixel range) where it's breaking  we can write media query and resize the contents properly.

Comment: I looked in the bootstrap code and there are around 100 lines of code to change if you want to change it yourself. I think the custom bootstrap is the best approach.

Comment: Yes, that did. depending on screen size, I am writing my own media query to reset size of my components and it works too.